# Why doesn't Rin save Saber in episode 24 of Unlimited Blade Works?

Tags: fate-stay-night

In the anime Unlimited Blade Works OVA, Rin rescues Saber before she disappears.
Why doesn't she do the same in the main anime (episode 24)? In that anime episode, she doesn't do or say anything to help Saber (whereas with Archer she begs him and cries when he doesn't accept). What can possibly make Rin change her mind in the OVA? (I haven't read the visual novel and don't intend to, so feel free to talk about it if it gives relevant info related to Rin.)

Also, does Rin try to save Archer in the OVA? (We don't see what happens but since she already saves Saber and she would consume most of her prana, asking Archer would be very selfish (poor Saber) so she shouldn't ask Archer. In that case, why would she abandon Archer (her real servant) and choose Saber?
(Again, if you know something relevant from the VN please tell me.)

Edit: Apparently Rin does ask Archer to stay in the OVA as well (VN source). Why would she do that when there's no mana for 2 servants? Is she just too greedy (to the point of being plain stupid and dying because of that) or does she intend to abandon Saber?

Comment: Related? But I didn't ask about Archer's case: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/23856/2604

Comment: It sure is related =P Apparently according to one of the posts Rin does ask archer to stay even in the ending in which she saves saber. Wow, that's weird ...

Comment: Someone called senshin changed lots of things in my question (capital letters, grammar...) Why? I think it was perfectly readable before, but thanks =P (I'll take more care next time)

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/37448/ubw-episode-25-true-ending-why-is-rin-sad-whenever-the-sun-sets-rises?noredirect=1&lq=1 Very related. This link directs to another question in this community that will make you understand the relationship between Rin and Archer when he dies at the end of UBW, necessary for understanding the difference between the good and true endings as we can understand Rin better. She still thinks about Archer in the true ending even after years have passed etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a side by side comparison between both the ova and episode 24. I repeated this 10-15 times to make sure. These are my findings:
During the first part until saber looks at her hand it is the same. After that it changes:

- In the ova saber smiles and starts disappearing. She seems less keener to go though. Just as saber starts smiling Rin runs to save her. Rin shows a lot of determination to save her as well.
- Episode 24: Rin completely forgets about saber. It is clear she's gonna disappear but she just mindlessly looks at the destroyed grail. Saber smiles and congratulates Rin, but Rin keeps staring at the destroyed grail. Saber is happier to go (her thoughts are "shrirou has you"). In the ova Rin starts running when saber smiles, but here she just forgets about saber.

Now that we have the facts clear let's answer your question:

1. The archer question: It was already answered by someone in the other thread someone linked you in the comments. What was said is:

"Something I didn't mention before but is quite relevant is that Rin either subsconciously or conciously chooses Archer (Shirou) over saber. She asks archer to remain in this world and cries when he doesn't accept. This happens in both the good and true ending (right before the good ending would come archer's scene).Think that if archer had accepted Rin's proposal both the true and happy endings would be the same (Rin - Shirou - Shirou). I do believe in the good ending Rin runs to save saber because of how much Shirou cares for her (at least 4 points given to her). Even so by asking archer to stay afterwards saber would have left this world had archer accepted (there's not enough mana for both of them and Rin knows it. She also knows saber isn't selfish to stay that way, by asking archer she's in a way betraying saber, that's why she thinks "I know I shouldn't ask" (but she does ask...) and archer says "I do not know if you will keep your contract with saber, but I am nor qualified for that")"

2. Why doesn't Rin save Saber in episode 24 of Unlimited Blade Works?

It would appear she forgets about her. If I had to guess I'd say that Shirou giving points to both girls plays a mayor role:

- True ending: Having received all the points Rin forgets about saber for some time. Shirou can live happily without saber and Rin can do the same. You could say Rin's mind is telling her everything's ok.
  (I'm assuming she never realises she's disappearing and that's why she's looking at where the noble phantasm was thrown. If she knows she's dying then she's a selfish BITCH). 
  Saber is also happier to go. She knows she doesn't play a big role in Shirou's life.
- Good ending: Rin's mind works perfectly and she quickly makes a dash towards saber. Rin knows Shirou needs saber and she likes spending time with saber as well. Her mind and body work at its fullest to saver her.
  Saber, knowing Shirou's love towards her, accepts. This is actually quite important. Both contitions are in my opinion relevant. If saber hadn't felt she's needed by Shirou she would have likely chosen death even if Rin had cried and begged her to stay (just like she did with archer)

My conclusion: In the end the one that plays the mayor role is Rin. I do believe she doesn't even remember saber cast her noble phantasm and is dying. You have to think that Rin can't just look at saber and say: hahahaha die you saber bitch!
Rin forgetting about saber is most likely the best option to show she cares a bit less about her but at the same time allowing her to keep her good nature (had she remembered she's dying just a few meters away she might have run to save her).
Then again it may also be that in her heart Rin accepted Shirou and her should be together just the 2 of them and purposely did it. We'll never know. I want to believe saber becomes less relevant and Rin just forgets about her, it's a much better interpretation.
Another valid theory is hesitation. Rin hesitates for a few seconds, just enough for it to be too late to save saber.
Just rest assured, she's not a cold-blooded murderer. If it were up to her I'm sure she'd rather everyone lives happily. The ova just shows that the good ending Tohsaka doesn't hesitate for even a second. The reason? It has to be that Shirou cares more about saber cause everything else is the same (Rin and saber have the exactly same relationship in both the good and true endings).

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/37448/ubw-episode-25-true-ending-why-is-rin-sad-whenever-the-sun-sets-rises?noredirect=1&lq=1 Very related. This link directs to another question in this community that will make you understand the relationship between Rin and Archer when he dies at the end of UBW, necessary for understanding the difference between the good and true endings as we can understand Rin better. She still thinks about Archer in the true ending even after years have passed etc

Answer (score 0):

Brief VN explanation: UBW's Good End is obtained by balancing Saber and Rin affection point so that you have enough Rin points to avoid the multiple Bad Ends, and dump the rest on Saber.

So, after Rin command Saber to destroy the grail, you are shown one of two intermissions, depending on the ending you're going to get:

New Wish (Good End): http://lparchive.org/Fatestay-night/Update%20235/1-UBW16-08a-1.jpg (due to the increased affection between her and Shirou). In this ending, Saber chose not to sever the Master Servant bond (0 command spell remaining after Rin used the last one to give her mana), and Rin chose to kept her, both for her sake (from Fate route you know that she's bi and attracted to Saber), and Shirou.

End of the Dream: What you saw in the anime. Saber obtained her answer watching the Archer Shirou conflict and is content leaving the world behind, as Shirou has Rin to keep him on the right path.

Comment: Nah, I think Rin's bi-curious at most. The h-scene in the V.N (fate route) was a life or death situation and it is an eroge, what happened there would have likeky been the same with other heroines, it's mostly fanservice. Also, the newer fate stay night version (realta nua, which is canon) completely removes that scene. Not to mention that in Fate Hollow Ataraxia once Rin and Shirou start a proper relationship there are several occasions in which Rin makes it clear she just wants Shirou as a love partner (like when Rin invites Shirou on a date to her private pool in her house,.. see next post

Comment: (Shirou says it's a great idea and that he's gonna tell saber and Rin gets super mad. She literally beats Shirou and tells him it's a couple's date, so just the 2 of them will go there). Moreover, I've read everything in the visual novels and there isn't one single scene in which saber even hints she likes Rin that way. A harem happens when +2 people around you loves you and in the visual novel saber literally says in the UBW good ending she's staying just for Shirou.

Comment: Lord, I don't think it is Shirou's harem either. Even if saber likes Shirou, she would never disturb their relationship. Saber ships Rin and Shirou and  says she will try not to be a nuisance. Sleeping with Shirou means betraying Rin (and Shirou in a way). Saber wouldn't do that.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments because they didnt make much sense since I wrote them in my cellphone. Basically thank you for your answer and that Nasu never said in an interview that Rin's bisexual when he's been asked so it's certainly not confirmed. I haven't read the VN but in the anime she's clearly straight.

Comment: About the command spells In the true ending Rin has to use the last one to force saber to destroy the Grail with Rin inside (killing her). Rin didn't die cause Archer saved her. In the good ending Saber willingly decides to destroy it (thinking she would kill Rin). So Saber may have stayed in the true ending if Rin had ran to make a new contract with her (as Rin did with archer). After all the true ending is the one where saber can't bring herself to kill Rin.

Comment: @Mare Whether saber confesses to Shirou or not it is still Shirou's harem. There is one route dedicated to the love between Shirou and Arturia. Saber never sees Rin that way (After Rin is forced to have sex with saber in the fate H-scene saber has eyes just for Shrirou, It's as if that never happened or rather it proves saber never even considered Rin a love interest). Also, in the UBW anime (and V.N) Rin says that Shirou cares too much for saber and that saber is too dedicated to Shirou.

Comment: In the UBW true ending Saber dies happy knowing that Shirou will be happy as well. In "the last episode" she waits for Shirou for thousands of years...